# Get refreshed data using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I know that while iterating on an IQueryable variable, a request is sent to the database, but if the data is updated in the database new data is not shown during the iteration until Refresh is not called on DataContext.

So what is the reason of always sending the request to the database if the updated data will not be available, and is there a way to always show updated data automatically without calling Refresh all the time?

I understand one advantage is that it returns newly added records, but what about updated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be helpful: [LINQ to SQL Tips 6: How to refresh given DataContext won't stomp on your objects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinesh.kulkarni/archive/2008/05/23/linq-to-sql-tips-6-how-to-refresh-given-datacontext-won-t-stomp-on-your-objects.aspx)

Also: [Refreshing the LINQ to SQL DataContext by Clearing the Cache](http://codebender.denniland.com/refreshing-the-linq-to-sql-datacontext-by-clearing-the-cache/)